# DISCORD BOT trying to make an RNG, but not recieving an answer when typing a command in Discord

Tags: python

I am trying to make an RNG bot to teach myself the basics of python in discord. when making an RNG command, my plan is to have a command (-RNG) for example, and find a random number to find an rng between 1, and the number chosen in the text. I have reached a boundary, and i am able to make the code work (in terms of there not being any errors) but my bot doesn't recognize the command and i get no response. any help/ideas?

Tried various codes from searching online, with none working as well as this one, having found this code from another forum online, but just unsure how to go about getting the command to work

```
import discord
import random
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.ext import commands


class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged in as')
        print(self.user.name)
        print(self.user.id)
        print('------')

    async def on_message(self, message):



            if message.content.startswith('-rng'):
                async def random1and10(ctx, number):
                    try:
                        arg = random.randint(1, int(number))
                    except ValueError:
                        await message.channel.send("Invalid number dumbass")
                    else:
                        await message.channel.send(str(arg))
```

expecting to be able to get a response from my bot, listing a random number with the max number being the number stated in the command to initiate it.

Answer (score 0):

This way won't work; you're going about this wrong. Look into the discord.py rewrite.

```py
from discord.ext import commands
import discord, random

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="-")

@commands.command()
async def rng(ctx, num):
    # ctx.channel is the channel the command was called in
    try:
        arg = random.randint(1, int(num))
    except ValueError:
        return await ctx.channel.send("Wrong number dumbass")
    else:
        return await ctx.channel.send(str(arg))
```

Now, If set up correctly the bot will call the rng() when you do -rng in your server.